# How to set IN values on an update (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server

Quick question, I did try to google but couldn't find an answer.

I have 3 separate queries here, I want to do `SET IN ('price1', 'price2', 'price3')` but when I tried I got an error. How would I do this?

```
Update apotable
set price1 = '0.00'
where po_number IN ('x', 'y', 'z')

Update apotable
set price2 = '0.00'
where po_number IN ('x', 'y', 'z')

Update apotable
set price3 = '0.00'
where po_number IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: It would be quite helpful to include the error message you got.

Answer (score 8):

```
Update apotable
   set price1 = 0, 
       price2 = 0,
       price3 = 0
where po_number IN ('x', 'y', 'z');
```

Note that numbers should not be enclosed in single quotes `0` is a number, `'0.00'` is a character literal (aka "string").

There is no need to search the web for the syntax of a SQL statement.
That is all documented in the manual: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx